Hot Chocolate stripping include from IQueryable
I have a model set up where I need to project into a sub object to get a field for a computed field on the parent object.
Use case:
class Transaction
{
    //PK
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key
    public Guid TypeId { get; set; }

    // holds info about the type of transaction sale, void, refund,  etc
    public TransType TransactionType { get; set; } 

    // underlying db value will always be positive
    private double _amount;

    public double Amount {
        get => _amount;
        set {
            //computation to allow amount to reflect actual effect on the account
            _amount = TransactionType.Multiplier * value; 
        }
    }
}

class TransType 
{
    // PK
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
  
    // will be 1 or -1
    [IsProjected(true)]
    public int Multiplier { get; set; }

    [GraphQLIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

I have attempted to relate these objects in EF Core using a one to many relationship and setting the AutoInclude property to true so the TransType would always be included.
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.TransactionType)
          .WithMany(p => p.Transactions)
          .HasForeignKey(d => d.TypeId);
 
    entity.Navigation(e => e.TransactionType).AutoInclude();
});

GraphQL query code:
[UseProjection]
[UseFiltering]
[UseSorting]
public IQueryable<Transaction> GetTransactions([ScopedService] DbContext db)
{
    return db.Transactions.Include(t => t.TransactionType);
}

My hope here is that when I try to access the Transaction object in Graphql, the Type obj will also be loaded and the amount multiplied so the true effect on the account is shown.
So a request like
transactions() { amount }

might produce data like
{
  "data": {
    "transactions": [
      {
        "amount":-12.75
      },
      {
        "amount":14.66
      }
    ]
   } 
}

However instead I get a null object error because the query didn't request the TransType info. I would assume that by putting a AutoInclude on the Navigation it would always load the TransType but it seems that somewhere in the Hot Chocolate library it is ignoring the include (I have also tried to manually do a .Include at the query level with the same results).
In this case I realize there is a work around since TransType is a finite list that I could just make a static map for, but I'd rather not so that the code doesn't have to be updated in the future if new types are added.
Is there any way to prevent Hot Chocolate from ignoring EF Core's Include? Or is any other way that you know of to allow for this type of projection into a sub object?
Versions for reference: .NET 6, Hot Chocolate 12

Include followed by Select is ignored., it ts what HotChocolate did under hood for loading just Amount. Use DTO instead of Model classes.  Something like that: return db.Transactions.Select(t => new TransactionDto { Amount = t.Amount * t.TransactionType.Multiplier, TransactionType = t.TransactionType ...}

So that does seem to allow for the desired functionally however it removes one of the benefits of using GraphQl. When I followed your suggestion, because I needed to copy all of the Transaction fields into the DTO, the SQl that was generated always contained selects for all of the fields in the DTO regardless of what the GraphQl request included. This thereby overfits the request.

Use Automapper and it's ProjectTo, it will simplify this mapping. You have not too much options here. Includes are just ignored by EF Core's design.
